# Downloading 1,000+ files fast?

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have a list of URLs that link to either images or MP4 files, what is the best way to recode this to run much faster? I know I could run multiple threads or even parallel but what's the best way?

I'm not too worried about speed as long as it isn't as slow as right now, but I don't want to overpower the device's resources such as CPU trying to speed it up.

```
public static void Download(string saveLocation, List<string> urls)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading: " + url);
            client.DownloadFile(url, saveLocation + "/" + url.Split('/').Last());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

It was just pointed out to me in a comment by **Jimi**, that [DownloadFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx) is an event driven call and not awaitable. Though, there is a [WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync(v=vs.110).aspx) version, which would be the appropriate one to use in this example, it is an awaitable call and returns a `Task`

> Downloads the specified resource to a local file as an asynchronous
> operation using a task object.

## Original answer

> I know I could run multiple threads or even parallel but what's the
> best way

Yes you can make it parallel and be in control of the resources you use.

> I'm not too worried about speed as long as it isn't as slow as right
> now, but I don't want to overpower the device's resources such as CPU
> trying to speed it up

You should be able to achieve this and configure this fairly well.

---

OK, so there are many ways to do this. Here are some things to think about:

- You have 1000s of [IO bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) tasks (as opposed to [CPU bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) tasks)
- With this many files, you want sort of parallelism and to be able to to configure the amount of concurrent tasks.
- You **will** want to do this in an `async` / `await` pattern so you're not wasting system resources on IO completion ports or smashing your CPU

Some immediate solutions:

- Tasks, and [`WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) in an `asnyc` / `await` pattern, this is a great approach however it's a little bit trickier to limit concurrent tasks.
- You have the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2), this has a nice approach to limit concurrent workloads, but its just not suited to IO bound tasks
- Or another option you might consider is the *Microsoft* [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), I have come to like these libraries a lot lately as they can give you the best of both worlds.

**Please note**: there are many other approaches.

So `Parallel.ForEach` uses the thread pool. Moreover, *IO bound* operations will block those threads waiting for a device to respond and tie up resources. A general rule of thumb here is

- If you have *CPU bound* code, `Parallel.ForEach` is appropriate;
- Though if you have *IO bound* code, *Asynchrony* is appropriate.

In this case, downloading a file is clearly *I/O*, there is a `DownloadFileAsync` version, and 1000 files to download, so you are best to use `async`/`await` pattern and some type of limit on concurrent tasks

---

Here is a very basic example of how you might achieve this:

**Given**

```
public class WorkLoad
{
    public string Url {get;set;}
    public string FileName {get;set;}

}
```

**Dataflow example**

```
public async Task DoWorkLoads(List<WorkLoad> workloads)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        // add pepper and salt to taste
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                     };

   // create an action block
   var block = new ActionBlock<WorkLoad>(MyMethodAsync, options);

   // Queue them up
   foreach (var workLoad in workloads)
      block.Post(workLoad );

   // wait for them to finish
   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;

}

...

// Notice we are using the async / await pattern
public async Task MyMethodAsync(WorkLoad workLoad)
{
   
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading: " + workLoad.Url);
        await client.DownloadFileAsync(workLoad.Url, workLoad.FileName);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // probably best to add some error checking some how
    }
}
```

**Summary**

This approach gives you *Asynchrony*, it also gives you `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, it doesn't waste resources, and lets *IO* be *IO*

**Disclaimer**, DataFlow may not be where you want to be, however I just thought I'd give you some more information

**Disclaimer 2**, Also the above code has not been tested, I would seriously consider researching this technology first and doing your on due diligence thoroughly.

---

[**Loosely related demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zp4FEB)

Comment: I see a problem here, since `DownloadFileAsync` is not awaitable, it's event driven. This kicks out async from the method declaration and `ActionBlock` will complain.

Comment: @jimi thanks and good catch, which makes my whole spiel null and void. ill modify it soon

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed this answer. I've just tried it out and it has just a tiny problem, `client` isn't declared although I expect you just new up a web client for that. Other than that, great answer thank you.

Comment: Just noticed that II seem to be getting an error when trying to await `DownloadFileAsync` as its a void return type also.

Comment: @user692959239 you need to use DownloadFileTaskAsync

Comment: @user692959239 also yes just new it up

Answer (score 1):

Mark your function as `async` and use `DownloadFileAsync` to save the files.  Capture the list of tasks into a new list and just `await` that list with `Task.WhenAll(yourTasks)` before you return.

Comment: A code example for this would really help, I'm not sure why I would need a list of tasks and how that would work.

Comment: Obviously it wouldn't be good to make a task for every download (500+) so how would I go about partitioning the downloads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallel.ForEach to download files in parallel. I have used something like this in the past.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileDownloader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List allUrls = GetUrls().Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToList();

            Parallel.ForEach(allUrls, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, url =>
            {
                try
                {
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    string originalFileName = response.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath.Substring(response.ResponseUri.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    Stream streamWithFileBody = response.GetResponseStream();
                    using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Ebooks_New\" + originalFileName))
                    {
                        streamWithFileBody.CopyTo(output);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Downloded : " + originalFileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to Download : " + ex.ToString());

                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Finished : ************************");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static List GetUrls()
        {
            return new List() // Put list of URLs here
            {
                "http://ligman.me/1IW1oab  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1Uixtlq  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1R9Ubgt  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1H4VXHT  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1f8XUKy  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1HBEUPi  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1NDTZR4  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1Uiy2f9  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1epZ0QU  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1JIhgjA  ",
    "http://ligman.me/1CQX5uG  ",
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't run any faster on a dual processor machine. I also get an error: `Unable to Download : System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\users\admin\desktop\scraper\scraper\bin\Debug\downloads\username123\nz709zOcFR1qlk60o_480.mp4' because it is being used by another process.` twice when downloading 500 files.