# C# Nested Parallel.ForEach while inserting into SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, parallel-processing, ado.net, parallel.foreach

We have an object (XML or JSON) and we map it to a DTO successfully, it takes too long (5~7 minutes) to be inserted in our database, so we went through `Parallel.ForEach`, but eventually, we noticed that there are some data entered incorrectly, like the `Category` has all items with the same name, but other different properties are 100% correct, in other case, we noticed that all data are the same in one category, although, the provided JSON object doesn't have that.

I confess it is so fast, it takes less than a minute, but with wrong insertion, have a look below on the used code:

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "CategoryId": 1,
    "CategoryName": "Drinks",
    "SortOrder": 1,
    "Products": [
      {
        "ProductId": 100,
        "ProductName": "Black Tea",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "Price": 5,
        "Choices": []
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 101,
        "ProductName": "Turkish Coffee",
        "SortOrder": 2,
        "Price": 7.5,
        "Choices": []
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 102,
        "ProductName": "Green Tea",
        "SortOrder": 3,
        "Price": 6,
        "Choices": []
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 103,
        "ProductName": "Café Latte Medium",
        "SortOrder": 4,
        "Price": 10,
        "Choices": []
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 104,
        "ProductName": "Orange Juice",
        "SortOrder": 5,
        "Price": 11,
        "Choices": []
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 105,
        "ProductName": "Mixed Berry Juice",
        "SortOrder": 6,
        "Price": 12.5,
        "Choices": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CategoryId": 1,
    "CategoryName": "Meals",
    "SortOrder": 1,
    "Products": [
      {
        "ProductId": 200,
        "ProductName": "Breakfast Meal",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "Price": 16,
        "Choices": [
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3000,
            "ChoiceName": "Strawberry Jam",
            "SortOrder": 1,
            "Price": 0
          },
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3001,
            "ChoiceName": "Apricot Jam",
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "Price": 0
          },
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3002,
            "ChoiceName": "Orange Jam",
            "SortOrder": 3,
            "Price": 0
          },
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3003,
            "ChoiceName": "Café Latte",
            "SortOrder": 4,
            "Price": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ProductId": 201,
        "ProductName": "Mixed Grill",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "Price": 30,
        "Choices": [
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3004,
            "ChoiceName": "Moutabal",
            "SortOrder": 1,
            "Price": 0
          },
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3005,
            "ChoiceName": "Mineral Water",
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "Price": 0
          },
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3006,
            "ChoiceName": "French Fries",
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "Price": 0
          },
          {
            "ChoiceId": 3007,
            "ChoiceName": "Grilled Potatoes",
            "SortOrder": 2,
            "Price": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**C# code**

```
Parallel.ForEach(categories, (category) =>
{
    var newCreatedCategoryId = 0;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_INTO_CATEGORIES", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", category.CategoryName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", category.SortOrder);
            newCreatedCategoryId = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            command.Dispose();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    if (newCreatedCategoryId > 0)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(category.Products, (product) =>
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_INTO_PRODUCTS", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", product.ProductName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", product.Price);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", product.SortOrder);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P4", newCreatedCategoryId);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Dispose();
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995648/parallel-foreach-with-sql-inserts-c-sharp), but this is not our issue, we are already using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last generated identity in the current scope of execution.

On the other hand, it is not allowed to use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert this amount of data even if with no `TableLock`.

Comment: Can you post the actual code? The reason I ask is that normally you have to specify `CommandType` as `StoredProcedure` on `SqlCommand` to pass parameters, which leads me to think this isn't your actual code.

Comment: How big is your json? how many lines are you generating?

Comment: By the way, you may find it faster to use "table valued parameters".

Comment: And this kids, is why you don't let people play with dbs and parallel foreach :) seriously though, this is not thread safe

Comment: You might want to tweak your loop with some `ParallelOptions`, otherwise the high number of requests will actually slow down the command execution on the SQL side. How I know? 1st hand experience ;) But as @TheGeneral already wrote. This by no means thread safe.

Comment: @john ... yeah it's not my actual one, but it is the same, and I have updated the missing line of adding `CommandType`. On the other hand, `TableValuedParameter` is not recommended by our DBAs as it breaks the common logic which we are using in the current system db

Comment: @BugFinder, the XML/JSON object we got contains about 27K lines, the minimum size we receive is about 800KB for each object ... let's say that we have 10 Categories, and each Category has 15 Products, and each Product has 20 Choices

Comment: @MarkusDeibel, so, you mean if I have multiple concurrent DB calls, it leads to have more time to get the whole operation done in less time???

Comment: Yes, in this case the DB server becomes the bottleneck, because it might (note that this depends on the server settings) just block any excess calls. If it only allows 16 parallel connections from one client and you bombard it with 32, 64 or even more the ones above the limit are block anyway. Anyway threadsafety is the main issue here. Get it fixed first.

Comment: @TheGeneral, for the non thread-safe which you pointed to, I think you mean the second `Parallel.ForEach` as it accesses the variable `newCreatedCategoryId`, correct? If so, do you think better to move the second/nested `Parallel.ForEach` to another separated method and pass the `newCreatedCategoryId` to it?

Answer (score 5):

Its the `newCreatedCategoryId` that is the problem, what is confusing me is why you are calling `newCreatedCategoryId = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` again in the inner loop. i mean if its just an id of category it doesn't need to be incremented again.

Take a look at the below edit. You might also be better to just put the second `Parallel.ForEach` into a standard `foreach` i mean this is all working in parallel anyway. Lastly Parallel.ForEach is not really suited to IO tasks, the correct pattern is async and await. on saying that you could probably use an ActionBlock out of TPL Dataflow to take advantage of the best of both worlds. Take a look at the dataflow example in the this question i answered [Downloading 1,000+ files fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972447/downloading-1-000-files-fast/49972755#49972755)

```
Parallel.ForEach(categories, (category) =>
{
    var newCreatedCategoryId = 0;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_INTO_CATEGORIES", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", category.CategoryName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", category.SortOrder);
            newCreatedCategoryId = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            command.Dispose();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    if (newCreatedCategoryId > 0)
    {
        foreach(product in category.Products)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_INTO_PRODUCTS", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", product.ProductName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", product.Price);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P3", product.SortOrder);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P4", newCreatedCategoryId);
                    command.Dispose();
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }//);
    }
});
```

Comment: For the code, it was a copy/past error from my side, I just call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` there, but is it an issue to access `newCreatedCategoryId` from the nested `Parallel.ForEach` ??

Comment: @RahmaAbdulhameed there is no real thread problem if that was just a copy and paste error, ie its all self contained and should work

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but what is the issue from your point of view? or what can I try from my side to test it once again

Comment: @RahmaAbdulhameed try the changes i made, does it still happen?

Comment: I can see that you have converted the nested `Parallel.ForEach` to sequential `foreach`, and I which I could have nested `Parallel.ForEach`, but I will give it a try multiple times to see if I get the same issue or not ... but, may you clarify what is the purpose of that conversion? would it help in solving this issue? in other works, was it the cause?

Comment: @RahmaAbdulhameed from the code you have shown, i am not really sure (especially if that second result was a copy and paste error) however if this a capture /closure or thread safe thing, the foreach should fix it

Answer (score 1):

The objects that you are looping over are not thread-safe. You could add a lock object however this would serialise the operation and defeat the purpose of the `Parallel.Foreach. You need to change the`Parallel.ForEach to a standard ForEach loop.

[Potential Pitfalls in Data and Task Parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism)

Answer (score 0):

You change the newCreatedCategoryId inside the Parallel.ForEach, which may cause incorrect data, because the queries wont run in order.

Comment: this was an copy/past error, I edited it here as in my app, I don't do that